# Alkaline "% full" from voltage?

Tags: batteries

Is there an equation or even a graph I can look at that appropriates the % full of an alkaline battery?

Comment: Did you have a specific type of alkaline battery, e.g. AA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's usually a V vs. Ah curve in the datasheet for the model of the battery, which you chose.  If the battery comes from a reputable manufacturer, the datasheets may be available on the web.

Example: [image] from [here](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/490/MN1500_US_CT-2796.pdf).  
In addition to the [useful link](http://www.powerstream.com/AA-tests.htm), which Brian had posted.

You can also make your own measurements and generate/verify the curves.  You would characterize the battery yourself.

Keep in mind that the curve is dependent on temperature and rate of discharge.  Essentially, there is a family of these nonlinear curves.  It's usually not practical to try to account for these parameters.  As a result, the error can easily be as large as 20%.  Battery voltage measurement could be an adequate approach if all that's needed is to make a threshold comparison and blink a "battery low" indicator.

Answer (score 2):

Just monitoring the voltage to estimate the condition of a battery is an approach that just does not work very well. The alkalyne battery voltage versus voltage curves are anything but linear and vary according to a number of factors like temperature, pre deployment shelf life, manufacturer, chemistry and discharge rate.

I have found that there are some other ways to assess battey life that may be a bit better than by trying to just monitor voltage behavior.

One system I actually designed into a product years ago used a method where the measurement process used a transistor to switch on a temporary load on the battery. The load was more than the normal discharge rate of the battery by two to five times. Voltage under load was monitored, then the load was released and the voltage change curve after that was monitored for a period of time. The total time of the load being applied was short, no more than a millisecond or so. The repetition time of the test was made slow enough so that the net loss of battery capacity had a very small impact on battery longevity. Could even be only once per day. It was fairly easy to characterize this methodology for a particular battery family so that a battery life meter in the product display was surprisingly accurate.

Another system I designed into a shrink wrapped battery pack used one of the many battery "gas gauge" chips that are on the market. These chips monitor current flow out of the battery by measuring the small voltage drop across a series shunt resistor that is in the battery lead. Note that these "gas gauge" chips are most often meant to be used for re-chargeable batteries but can also be used for a discharge only application as well. This measurement scheme does a pretty good job of accumulating the the total energy drawn from a battery pack. When used in conjunction with a thermistor that be used to monitor and compensate for temperature effects you can end up with a system that is much better than simply measuring the battery voltage.

Both of these schemes require some engineering characterization and testing work to fine tune the algorithms used and produce the final implementation. That work can be kind of fun to do.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, unless you know the current draw and the manufacturer.

There are [such curves](http://www.powerstream.com/AA-tests.htm). However they depend on battery manufacturer since some are more cheaply made. Also higher currents result in less power being provided due to resistance and chemical effects.

Comment: I mean under no load.  For example, if I have a AA battery that reads 1.2volts - would I be able to know that it is 50%?

Comment: @KeeganMcCarthy: No.